# I am getting Class not found exception even passing jar file

Tags: karate

My feature file looks like:

test.feature

```
Feature: Send http request
  Background:
    * def payoutSerivce = Java.type('farm.nurture.core.contracts.PayoutService')

  Scenario: do it
    * print payoutSerivce
```

I am passing a jar file while running the feature file:

```
java -cp karate.jar;libpayout_service_java_grpc-src.jar com.intuit.karate.Main "test.feature"
```

I am getting the following error:
evaluation (js) failed: Java.type('farm.nurture.core.contracts.PayoutService'), java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: farm.nurture.core.contracts.PayoutService

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry this is one of those problems where it is impossible to help you remotely. read the linked answers and try your best, take help from people next to you if possible. if all else fails, use a java project: https://youtu.be/W-af7Cd8cMc